# How to group text being typed into an array and wrap every 20 chars in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, contenteditable

I am attempting to wrap every 20 chars in a new div container.  I keep getting undefined I assume from the array results that do not exist yet.  How can I wrap every 20 chars as the user types and reaches char 20, 40, 60,and 80 and place it into a div container with the max allowed chars being 80, and is there a better way of doing this than writing out the array groups manually by 20's.

```js
function creaeTextField(clicked_id) {
  var dropArea = document.getElementById('headarea');
  var myArea = document.createElement('div');
  var myAreaOuter = document.createElement('div');

  myArea.className = "areaClass";
  myAreaOuter.className = "areaClassOuter";

  myArea.id = "areaClass";
  myAreaOuter.id = "areaClassOuter";

  myArea.contentEditable = "true";

  if (clicked_id == 'text') {
    myAreaOuter.appendChild(myArea);
    dropArea.appendChild(myAreaOuter);

    myArea.addEventListener("keydown", findLimitb);
    myArea.addEventListener("keyup", findLimitb);

    var style = window.getComputedStyle(myArea, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    var fontSize = parseFloat(style);

    function findLimitb() {
      if (myArea.offsetHeight <= fontSize * 4) {
        myArea.addEventListener("keydown", breaker);
      } else {
        if (event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 38 || event.keyCode === 39 || event.keyCode === 40) {
          myArea.focus();
        } else {
          myArea.removeEventListener("keydown", breaker);
          event.preventDefault();
          myArea.style.height = fontSize * 4 + "px";
        }
      }
    }

    function breaker() {
      var myAr = myArea.innerHTML.split("");
      var divCon = document.createElement('div');
      myArea.appendChild(divCon);
      if (myArea.innerHTML.length > 20) {
        divCon.innerHTML = myAr[0] + myAr[1] + myAr[2] + myAr[3] + myAr[4] + myAr[5] + myAr[6] + myAr[7] + myAr[8] + myAr[9] + myAr[10] + myAr[11] + myAr[12] + myAr[13] + myAr[14] + myAr[15] + myAr[16] + myAr[17] + myAr[18] + myAr[19] + myAr[20];
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.headarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 130px;
  float: left;
}

.buttonStyle {
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
}

.areaClassOuter {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 29;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
}

.areaClass {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 310px;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-height: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  border: 1px #000000 solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headarea" id="headarea"></div>
<button class="buttonStyle" id="text" type="button" onclick="creaeTextField(this.id)"></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just listen for the `keydown`-event like you did in your question and then work with `substring` to get and remove the first part of the string. The first part can then be appended to an container and the rest of the string (in most cases only 1 char) can be set as content of the input-element.

you should also consider using `textContent` instead of `innerHtml`, so that the user is able input safely characters that are used by html.

```js
let textOutput = document.getElementById('textOutput');
let textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
let maxInputLength = 20;
let maxOutputElement = 4; // 4*20 = 80 Chars

textInput.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (textOutput.children.length >= maxOutputElement) {
    event.preventDefault();
    textInput.textContent = '';
  }
  let textChanged = false;
  let text = textInput.textContent;
  while (text.length >= maxInputLength) {
    let firstPart = text.substring(0, maxInputLength);
    let textElement = document.createElement('div');
    textElement.textContent = firstPart;
    textElement.contentEditable = true;
    textElement.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
      let editText = event.currentTarget.textContent;
      if (editText.length >= maxInputLength) {
        event.currentTarget.textContent = editText.substring(0, maxInputLength);
      }
    });
    textOutput.appendChild(textElement);
    text = text.substring(maxInputLength);
    textChanged = true;
  }
  if (textChanged) textInput.textContent = text;
});
```

```css
#textOutput div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

#textInput {
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="textOutput"></div>
<div id="textInput" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: This is close to what im looking for, but the user can't edit the divs after being removed from the content editable div.

Comment: You can do this, like you did in your question. I updated my answer with a simple implementation for editing the divs. I also limited the divs to max 20 chars. You can extend on that depending on the behavior you need, like allowing only certain characters or remembering/restoring the current selection/carret-position. Or special-cases like copy&paste, returns etc.

Comment: Thank you. This will work for me.  Ill do a little tweaking to it but much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string into spaces and use a modulus to see when 20 items have been reached.

This makes the code independent and allows you to change the number of words allowed in each string.

We split on the space and then iterate over the words, we reconstruct the string but push the results into an array when we reach the 'paragraphlength'. You then end up with an array of strings that are 20 words long.

There are some edge cases that aren't covered here and may not be an issue depending on your use case. For example, what if a user just puts illegible characters in, ect

```js
//The wording as a string
const words = "this is a really long set of words that need to be broken down into a paragraphs array that has lots of words that need to be broken down into a nicer structure for users to easier consume. We split on the space and then iterate over the words, we reconstruct the string but push the results into an array when we reach the 'paragraphlength'";

const getParagraphs = (words, paragraphLength) => {
  let paragraphs =[];
  words.split(" ").reduce((memo, word, index) => {
    if(index > 0 && index % paragraphLength === 0)
    {
        paragraphs.push(memo);
        memo = "";
    }
    return memo + " " + word;
  }, "");
  return paragraphs
}

const paragraphs = getParagraphs(words, 20);
console.log("original string ===>", words);
console.log("paragraphs array ===>", paragraphs);
//below is for display purposes only
let results = document.getElementById('results');
paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
  const para = document.createElement("p");
  const node = document.createTextNode(paragraph);
   para.appendChild(node);
   results.appendChild(para);
});
```

```html
<div id="results">
</div>
```